# How do I get the contents from the table and put it into a table using form post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, postgresql, express

so in my project I'm trying to get the contents from a table row and send it back to the backend using form post, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's my code for the HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/add">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="class_form">
            <h3>Choose your course</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <select name="institution" id="institution" onchange="getInstTermVal(event)">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose college...</option>
                    <option value="BAR01">Baruch College</option>
                    <option value="QNS01">Queens College</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <select id="term" name="term" onchange="getInstTermVal(event)">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Term...</option>
                    <option value="1179" >Fall Semester 2017</option>
                    <option value="1182" >Spring Semester 2018</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <select id="subject" name="subject">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Subject...</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type="number" id="course_num" name="course_num" placeholder="Course Number">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <button type="button" id="submit_class" onclick=getSpecificCourse(event)>Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive-vertical" id="class_table">
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Class Number</th>
                    <th>Day & Time</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Instructor</th>
                    <th>Select</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_body">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my JS code where I append to the table_body:

```
    function getSpecificCourse(event){
            for(let secKey in classes[key]){
                        if(classes[key].hasOwnProperty(secKey)) {
                            let classNmbr = classes[key][secKey].Class;
                            let dayTime = classes[key][secKey]['Days & Time'];
                            let room = classes[key][secKey].Room;
                            let instructor = classes[key][secKey].Instructor;
                            document.getElementById("table_body").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = `<td class="classNmbr">${classNmbr}</td>` +
                                    `<td>${dayTime}</td>` +
                                    `<td>${room}</td>` +
                                    `<td>${instructor}</td>` +
                                    `<td><button type="submit" class="submit_cart">Add to cart</button></td>`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to get the class number as well as the values in the college and term and subject but to do that I just say req.body.institution or req.body.term but I don't know how I'd call the class number from the table row when they click the button.

Here's a snippet from express.js where I try to add it to the database:

```
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    db.query("INSERT INTO classes (institution, term, subject, topic, class_num, phone, carrier) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)",
        [req.body.institution, req.body.term, req.body.subject, req.body.topic, req.body.class_num, req.body.phone, req.body.carrier], (error, response) => {
        if (error){
            return console.error('Error inserting into database: ', error);
        }
    });
});
```

If someone can help me that would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Offtopic: What's with the jQuery part? Just to remove the rows? `document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML = ""` or `document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach(tr => tr.remove());`, or ...

Comment: Yea it's just remove all the rows so when they say change college and submit again it'd delete all the rows from the previous request and append the new rows. Are you saying that's a better way to do it?

Comment: Please scale this down to a minimal representation of only the specific problem. See [mcve]. If it is a row click problem we don't need to see your back end code...if it is a back end problem we don't need to see most of the front end rendering code

Comment: Of course sorry, the issue is that I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I think it's just that I'm unaware of how to get it done. I removed some unnecessary code though. I just want to figure out how to get the inner text of class="classNmbr" and then put it into the table like req.body.classNmbr.

Comment: Not necessarily better. With all thia fancy ES6/7 stuff I was just curious why you would then use jQuery for a simple task such as removing the rows of a table.